# Transition from inertial to kinetic range in Solar wind turbulence

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun, turbulence, magnetohydrodynamics

Most papers studying the turbulence in the solar wind present figures showing the power spectral density (PSD) of the magnetic field. The inertial range, with a power law index of ~ -5/3, is followed by the kinetic range that follows a steeper power law index.

This change seems to occur at ion scales, to my understanding at either the proton inertial length, $d = v_{A}/\Omega_{p}$, or the proton gyroradius.

I have two questions:

1. Is the proton inertial scale or the proton gyroradius the correct transition point to kinetic ranges?
2. Both proton inertial scale and the proton gyroradius depend on the heliospheric distance. Does this mean that at different heliospheric distances the transition scale between inertial and kinetic changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the proton inertial scale or the proton gyroradius the correct transition point to kinetic ranges?

It's actually both.  Well, it's the smaller of the two, since they are not necessarily the same in all regions.  In the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) near Earth, the two are usually very close to one another but in other regions of space they can differ greatly.  See Section 3.7.3 and references therein of *Wilson et al.* [2021] for more details.

> Both proton inertial scale and the proton gyroradius depend on the heliospheric distance. Does this mean that at different heliospheric distances the transition scale between inertial and kinetic changes?

Yes and when the two spatial scales flip, the type of dissipating fluctuations can change as well.

## **References**

Wilson, L.B., *et al.*, "A Quarter Century of *Wind* Spacecraft Discoveries," *Reviews of Geophysics* **59**(2), pp. e2020RG000714, doi:[10.1029/2020RG000714](https://doi.org/10.1029/2020RG000714), 2021.